# How to prevent cy.get from "snapshotting" a list before it's sorted

Tags: dom, cypress

Not the best title, but here's my challenge. I have a list on my page that can be sorted, and I want a Cypress test that checks that it works as expected. So imagine this test:

```js
/* 1 */ cy.get('.list-item').eq(0).should('have.text', 'A');
/* 2 */ cy.get('.list-item').eq(-1).should('have.text', 'Z');

// Code that triggers sorting to change from asc to desc

/* 3 */ cy.get('.list-item').eq(0).should('have.text', 'Z');
/* 4 */ cy.get('.list-item').eq(-1).should('have.text', 'A');
```

Looks simple, but there's a slight delay when the sorting happens, so the UI isn't updated *immediately*.

I'm not sure if it's the `cy.get` or the `eq` function which causes it, but the problem is that line 3 "captures" the first element in the list, which is still `'A'`, and *then* tries to assert that the text is `'Z'`. And when the list is reordered, this "captured" element doesn't actually change, it's just moved in the DOM, so the assertion *still* tries to assert that same element `'A'`, which in the DOM is actually the last element now, is `'Z'`, which it obviously isn't and shouldn't be.

If I insert a `cy.wait(100)` before 3, then it works as expected, but obviously I do not want to have a random wait in my test, so how do I solve this?

How do I check what the first and last elements are in a situation like this, when Cypress captures the DOM elements *before* they're reordered, without inserting an arbitrary wait?

---

### Actual case

- Support app, showing a list of the 5 most recently viewed clients
- Need to test that, when visiting for example number 3 in that list, it is moved to the top
- The "code that triggers sorting" is actually a route navigation event:

  1. There's a listener (React `useEffect` hook) on route changes.
  2. When route changes, it updates the list of recently viewed client ids, which is stored in local storage.
  3. When the list in local storage changes, the component showing the list first waits 750ms (so it's less confusing for user, but turned down to 10ms in Cypress tests), then updates (re-sorts) the list.
  4. And since the list only contains ids, each tile will then async load the name and some more stuff to display on the list item.

So... the delay is actually more than just a UI update. There's routing, local storage and async requests involved too.

Comment: Can you click on something else (that doesn't do anything) to cause that momentary delay, or `focus()` on an input field followed by `;blur()` ?

Comment: @Mikkel Actual case is a bit more complex, so not really, hehe. Also pretty much as much fan of random focus/blur stuff as I am of random wait 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge `cy.get(...)` and `.eq` into a single selector to make sure it retries the assertion `.should('have.text', 'Z')` after resorting. Read about it https://on.cypress.io/retry-ability#Merging-queries - right now it grabs the list and then only retries `.eq()` command, which is too late. You could also rewrite your code to get the first and last elements using single `.should(cb)` https://on.cypress.io/should#Function - the example in the docs really fits your use case.

Comment: That looks promising! Will try it out at work tomorrow 

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a wild shot here, but perhaps in the trigger to sort you could use then.

```
    cy.get('.list-item').eq(0).should('have.text', 'A');
    cy.get('.list-item').eq(-1).should('have.text', 'Z');

    // Code that triggers sorting to change from asc to desc
    cy.get("#id-to-sort").click().then(()=>{

    cy.get('.list-item').eq(0).should('have.text', 'Z');
    cy.get('.list-item').eq(-1).should('have.text', 'A');

    })
```

Comment: I have added a description of the actual case, which is a bit more complex than the very simplified example I asked about, so there's not actually any button clicking involved. But this does look similar to the `should` with callback, as suggested by @gleb-bahmutov, so might try something similar to that/this 