# Using Cypress - how to find adjacent items in a certain state

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have a long table with status buttons:

[image]

```
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Not Met</button>
</td>
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-warning">N/A</button>
</td>
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-danger">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">N/A</button>
</td>
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-success">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">N/A</button>
</td>
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-danger">Not Met</button>
</td>
```

I need to find a Not Met button with class btn-danger, which also has an adjacent N/A button (with class btn-teriary) and click the N/A button.

I'm a bit lost in all the Cypress options of get, find, within, etc.

I can find one of the buttons but not sure the best approach how to verify it also has the additional button next to it, and that both buttons have the expected classes.

My issue is I need to find the button, with a specific class, adjacent to another button with a specific class. Psuedo code:

```
cy.contains('Not Met').and('has.class', 'btn-danger').next().contains('N/A).and('has.class', 'btn-tertiary')...and then somehow click the Not Met button :)
```

Comment: Do you need to click on the 'Not Met' button or the N/A button in second row ? Could you also please post the full html of that table..

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question, you wish to click on the `N/A` button next to the 'Not Met' button in the second row. For that you could try the below approach. I have tried in local and this is working for me, please let me know how it goes !
If the table has got some id or unique class name use that, else use `table`. You could use `next()` method to reach the N/A button and `:nth-child(3)` for getting the correct row.

```
it("Check if cypress click the N/A button in the third row", () => {
    cy.visit('url_here');
    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.get('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > button').contains("Not Met").next().click();      
})
```

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot and clarified my text a bit

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer, please have a look.

Comment: Should tr be td?

Answer (score 0):

**Resolving the first button**

```js
cy.contains('Not Met').and('has.class', 'btn-danger')
```

This fails because `cy.contains('Not Met')` yields a single subject, and the first button that has the text 'Not Met' does not have the required class.

I recently saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59880887/4716245) that mentioned 'merging selectors', which is a useful principle when selectors are not specific enough, i.e you can move the 'btn-danger' test up the chain:

```js
cy.get('button[class*=btn-danger]').contains('Not Met')

OR 

cy.contains('button[class*="btn-danger"]', 'Not Met')
```

The first selector now looks for a button with class attribute ([class...]) containing (*=) "btn-danger", and has text 'Not Met'.

**Correctly finding the companion button**

The above succeeds with the sample html you gave, but to properly test the companion button we need to make it a bit more difficult by duplicating the row you are targeting and changing the companion button in the first to 'btn-warning', i.e

```html
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Not Met</button>
</td>
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-warning">N/A</button>
</td>

<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-danger">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-warning">N/A</button>      <-- not what we seek
</td>

<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-danger">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">N/A</button>     <-- this is the one
</td>


<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-success">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Not Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">N/A</button>
</td>
<td class="evaluation-button-cell">
  <button class="conduct btn btn-tertiary">Met</button>
  <button class="conduct btn btn-danger">Not Met</button>
</td>
```

The problem with

```js
cy.get('button[class*=btn-danger]').contains('Not Met')

OR 

cy.contains('button[class*="btn-danger"]', 'Not Met')
```

is that they only return a single subject - although there are three buttons that fit, only the first is returned.

This can be solved by also merging the `contains()` part into the first selector,

```js
cy.get("button[class*='btn-danger']:contains('Not Met')")
```

which yields the three buttons that meet the criteria.

To get the button with the correct companion button, use `next()` with a selector of the same pattern,

```js
cy.get("button[class*='btn-danger']:contains('Not Met')")
  .next("button[class*='btn-tertiary']:contains('N/A')")
  .click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The 'merging selectors' is a great technique I was not aware of.

Comment: I didn't read your questions correctly - you want to click the 'N/A' button, not the 'Not Met' button, removed some steps not required.